# Get number of app active users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wonder if there's a way to get a number of active users of my app sending an API request. Does Facebook provide such function?

I surely can look it up in my app's Dashboard, but I need to do it automatically to balance number of requests in order not to reach the limits.

P.S. I know, I can use Webhooks not to reach the limits, but I still didn't recieve the answer how can I use them for the aims that I need.

Comment: have you found a good solution to find the number of users/ balance API calls?

Comment: @gereb95 I posted an answer below. If this is not an answer to your question, then, please, rephrase it, cause I didn't get what you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As scripted testing showed, there are no limits for *THIS* requests. I just set up an sh-script that send lots of requests, and my dashboard showed no alert, nor I received on email or somewhere else, so I decided to use it as often as I need, not worrying about limits.